How to consolidate multiple Docker containers in a Kubernetes pod but maintain separate deployability?
I'm working on a project where I currently have separate services deployed in separate pods within Kubernetes. However, I'm exploring the possibility of consolidating multiple Docker containers into a single Kubernetes pod while maintaining the ability to deploy each container individually without affecting the others.
This setup is essential for our development workflow, as it allows multiple developers to work on each Docker image independently and deploy them to a test environment without interfering with each other's services.
Note: Running each container on a separate pod has been considered; however, due to specific project requirements and constraints, this approach is not feasible for us. Therefore, I'm seeking advice and solutions specifically tailored to managing multiple containers within a single pod.
I'd appreciate any guidance or best practices on how to achieve this configuration effectively in Kubernetes. Thank you!

In most cases I'd suggest that you should only run one container in a Pod (and that your Pods should always be managed by Deployments or other higher-level objects).  Would it work for your use case to keep your existing deployment structure, but give each developer a separate Namespace?

Building on @Jonas's answer, you can't update or redeploy an individual container within a Pod.  Why do you think a separate Deployment per microservice won't work for you?


I'm exploring the possibility of consolidating multiple Docker containers into a single Kubernetes pod while maintaining the ability to deploy each container individually without affecting the others.

No, this is not possible. Pod is the deployment unit in Kubernetes.

I strongly advice against your approach.
Technically you can have multiple containers in a Pod and even change the image at runtime. But you can't change the Pod configuration.
Besides there are better suited tools, look into

https://skaffold.dev/
https://www.telepresence.io/

